Add a word to the default or custom dictionary
I know how to check if a word is in the dictionary using Application.CheckSpelling, but I can't find any information on how to add words to the default dictionary or a custom dictionary, using VBA code in Excel.
I've read that, in the case of a custom dictionary, you just have to add the words to the file that contains the dictionary, but I don't know how to do this either.
Own answer:
The default custom dictionary for all languages ​​is RoamingCustom.dic, which can be modified through the following menu of the application File/Options/Review/Custom Dictionaries/ and allows you to add or delete words to its content, as well as modify the default dictionary, but you cannot delete the dictionary because it is the default one for Office. This dictionary also does not show its path, as the default dictionaries in English and Spanish do.
However, the default dictionary RoamingCustom.dic is still an editable .dic text file, located in the following path:
C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\16.0\c7190f46\Proofing\
where 16.0 is the version of Office and can be another, and c7190f46 can also be any other value.
There is another custom dictionary that we can add, called CUSTOM.DIC, which is located in the following path:
C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof\
This dictionary can be configured for any language or for a specific language, which modifies the file header to a specific #LID (language identifier number) value.
If the CUSTOM.DIC dictionary is configured for any language, it can be set as the default instead of RoamingCustom.dic.
Regarding the question of whether you can add words to an Office dictionary using VBA code, the answer is that the only way to do this is to add the words to the .dic text file.
Handling text files is not complicated, the only important requirement to keep in mind in this case is that the file must be opened in UNICODE format, using the FSO file system (Scripting.FileSystemObject):
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Open the file for reading:
Err.Clear
Set f= FSO.OpenTextFile(dicFileName, 1, True, -2) 'read, create 
                                         if necessary, UNICODE format
If Err <> 0 And Err <> 55 Then Exit Sub

'Load all the text from the file:
text = f.ReadAll()

'Close the file in read mode:
f.Close

'Open the file to "append" to the end!
Err.Clear
Set f= FSO.OpenTextFile(dicFileName, 8, True, -2) 'ForAppending, 
                                    create if necessary, UNICODE format
If Err <> 0 And Err <> 55 Then Exit Sub

If VBA.InStr(text, word) = 0 Then
   f.WriteLine word
End If

'Close file:
f.Close

'Release resources:
Set FSO = Nothing
Set f=Nothing


https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-add-word-list-to-custom-dictionary.203048/
