Application.SpellingOptions.UserDict does not work
According to the language reference, Application.SpellingOptions.UserDict instructs Microsoft Excel to create a custom dictionary to which new words can be added when performing spelling checks on a worksheet. Read/write String.
It works in read mode, returning the name of the default custom dictionary (CUSTOM.DIC, RoamingCustom.dic or any other set as default).
However, assigning it in write mode has no effect.
Application.SpellingOptions.UserDict = "dic1.dic"   '"CUSTOM.DIC"

Does anyone know how to use it to modify the default custom dictionary or create a new one?
Thanks.
Regards.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-add-word-list-to-custom-dictionary.203048/

Didn't you ask a very similar question already?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79262782/add-a-word-to-the-default-or-custom-dictionary

FYI dictionary locations: https://forums.ultraedit.com/storage-location-of-custom-dictionaries-t19563.html#:~:text=Here%20are%20the%20locations%20of,dic

Mical, very similar does not mean that it is the same. On the other hand, that question was answered (and then closed without a justified reason) through a comment by Tim Williams (I still don't understand why it is allowed to answer questions through comments, probably because the answers can be evaluated positively, but also negatively, and the comments cannot), and the concise answer was a reference to an external page (MrExcel) where the question is asked and answered in a more than questionable way. But as I say, they are two different questions.

Tim Williams, thanks for the info. I'll let you know when I can check it out.

Tim, I checked your link and it helped me find the path to RoamingCustom.dic, but it doesn't answer my question, but I appreciate the input.

Excel VBA doesn't offer much functionality for what you want to do, but you could use Word as a proxy to add a new dictionary.
For example:
Sub AddNewDict()

    Dim wdApp As Object, wasRunning As Boolean, dict, dicts
    
    SetWord wdApp, wasRunning
    
    Set dicts = wdApp.Application.CustomDictionaries
    
    'list out any existing custom dictionaries
    Debug.Print "-------Before--------"  
    For Each dict In dicts
        Debug.Print dict.Path & "\" & dict.Name
    Next dict
    
    'add a new dictionary
    'file encoding seems to be "ITF-16 LE" according to notepad...
    wdApp.Application.CustomDictionaries.Add _
         "C:\Users\yourUserNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof\custom33.dic"
    
    
    Debug.Print "-------After--------"
    For Each dict In dicts
        Debug.Print dict.Path & "\" & dict.Name
    Next dict
    
    If Not wasRunning Then wdApp.Quit 'close Word if we opened it
    
End Sub


'Set `wdApp` to an instance of Word, and `WasRunning` to
'  indicate whether Word was already open.
Sub SetWord(wdApp As Object, wasRunning As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    wasRunning = Not wdApp Is Nothing
    If Not wasRunning Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End Sub


Thanks Tim. You're actually answering the question I asked yesterday, which is where I would have wanted this answer, but I appreciate your input, because I'm slowly getting to understand how this works. Thanks again. Regards.
